# How can i get file url data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using base64 to get image data:

```js
function previewFile() {
  const preview = document.getElementById('video1');
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // convert to base64
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>

<video width="320" height="240" id="video1" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This script makes you upload an mp4 file and then it will display it.

The problem is that base64 is too way long. Is there any other way to get the file data but shorter?

Comment: Use `blob` url for shorter data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `Blob` url for shorter src.

**Convert Base64 to Blob**

Change:

```
reader.result
```

to:

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

```js
function previewFile() {
  const preview = document.getElementById('video1');
  const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
    // convert to base64
    preview.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>

<video width="320" height="240" id="video1" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```